# Android SoundPool: get notified when end of played

Tags: android, soundpool

This sound so simple that I can't figure out why I can't find the answer lol

I have a working sound pool class (thanks to a tutorial and some tweaking I did), and it works fine.

the problem now is that I want to be able to change my background music randomly. (not always have the same music in a loop but have 2 or 3 and when one finishes I play one of the 2 others).

problem is I can't find a way to get notified that the music has finished playing.

Any ideas ?

Jason

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can't be done with SoundPool as far as I can tell.

The only audio 'player' that I know which can provide a completion notification is 
[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) - it's more of a complex beast than SoundPool but allows setting an OnCompletionListener to be notified when playback is complete.

Comment: its the conclusion I drew but I wanted to be sure. I'll surely have to use Media player because SoundPool can't handle big sounds (over 100ko I read somewhere) thanks

Comment: What do you mean with ko?

Comment: @DanielG.R. : I suspect Jason Rogers simply meant 100k (as in 100 KB)  but the o key on a keyboard is near the k and he may have hit it by accident.

Comment: @JasonRogers SoundPool can handle files whose **uncompressed** stream is up to 1 MB or 1 MiB.

Answer (score 19):

This is what I do:

On **startup** I get the length of each sound-click using a MediaPlayer:

```
private long getSoundDuration(int rawId){
   MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(context, rawId);
   int duration = player.getDuration();
   return duration;
}
```

and store the sound plus the duration together (in a DTO-type object).

Comment: Thanks; +1. Note that you also call player.release() before returning.

Comment: Maybe that would be a good idea to export the duration of the audios via some offline tools, such as ffmpeg, and create a lookup table when app launches. AFAIK to create MediaPlayer will involve unexpected overhead.

Answer (score 7):

I have more than 100 short sound clips and SoundPool is my best option. I want to play one clip just after another clip is finished playing. Upon finding that there is no onCompletionListener() equivalent I chose to implement a runnable. This works for me because the first sound is between 1 and 2 seconds long so I have the duration of the runnable set at 2000. Hope they work on this class because its got lots of potential!

Comment: That's a good choice if a pause is required but its duration is not really important.

Answer (score 6):

MediaPlayer is heavy and slow compared with SoundPool, but SoundPool doesn't have setOnCompletionListener. To cope with this issue I implemented a [custom class](https://github.com/genhau/SoundPoolPlayer) from SoundPool with setOnCompletionListener.

usage: similar to MediaPlayer

### creation:

```
SoundPoolPlayer mPlayer = SoundPoolPlayer.create(context, resId);
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
    new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  //mp will be null here
            Log.d("debug", "completed");
        }
    };
);
mPlayer.play();
```

### pause:

```
mPlayer.pause();
```

### stop:

```
mPlayer.stop();
```

### resume:

```
mPlayer.resume();
```

### isPlaying:

```
mPlayer.isPlaying();
```

any pull request is welcomed. I only implemented what I need here.

Comment: How would you loop an audio with this?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem and created s SoundPool queue which enqueue the sounds to be played and notifies when each sound completes it's playback. It's in Kotlin but should be easy translated to Java.

```
class SoundPoolQueue(private val context: Context, maxStreams: Int) {
    companion object {
        private const val LOG_TAG = "SoundPoolQueue"
        private const val SOUND_POOL_HANDLER_THREAD_NAME = "SoundPoolQueueThread"
        private const val ACTION_PLAY_SOUND = 1

        @JvmStatic
        fun getSoundDuration(context: Context, soundResId: Int) : Long {
            val assetsFileDescriptor = context.resources.openRawResourceFd(soundResId)
            val mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()

            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(
                    assetsFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor,
                    assetsFileDescriptor.startOffset,
                    assetsFileDescriptor.length)

            val durationString = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)
            val duration = durationString.toLong()

            logDebug("SoundPoolQueue::getSoundDuration(): Sound duration millis: $durationString")

            assetsFileDescriptor.close()
            return duration
        }

        @JvmStatic
        private fun logDebug(message: String) {
            if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                return
            }

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, message)
        }
    }

    private var soundPool = if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val attrs = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                .build()

        SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(maxStreams)
                .setAudioAttributes(attrs)
                .build()
    }
    else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        SoundPool(maxStreams, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0)
    }

    var soundPoolQueueListener : SoundPoolQueueListener? = null

    private val soundPoolHandlerThread = SoundPoolQueueThread().apply { start() }
    private val soundPoolSoundsSparseArray = SparseArray<SoundPoolSound>()
    private val soundPoolSoundsQueue = LinkedList<SoundPoolSound>()

    fun addSound(soundResId: Int, leftVolume: Float, rightVolume: Float, priority: Int, loop: Boolean, rate: Float) {
        val durationMillis = getSoundDuration(context = context, soundResId = soundResId)
        val soundId = soundPool.load(context, soundResId, priority)

        soundPoolSoundsSparseArray.put(soundResId,
                SoundPoolSound(durationMillis, soundResId, soundId, leftVolume, rightVolume, priority, loop, rate))
    }

    fun playSound(soundResId: Int) {
        logDebug("SoundPoolQueue::playSound()")
        soundPoolSoundsQueue.add(soundPoolSoundsSparseArray[soundResId])
        soundPoolHandlerThread.handler?.sendEmptyMessage(ACTION_PLAY_SOUND)
    }

    inner class SoundPoolQueueThread : HandlerThread(SOUND_POOL_HANDLER_THREAD_NAME) {
        var handler: Handler? = null

        override fun onLooperPrepared() {
            super.onLooperPrepared()

            handler = object : Handler(looper) {
                override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg)

                    if(msg.what == ACTION_PLAY_SOUND && handler!!.hasMessages(ACTION_PLAY_SOUND)) {
                        return
                    }

                    if(soundPoolSoundsQueue.isEmpty()) {
                        logDebug("SoundPoolHandlerThread: queue is empty.")
                        handler!!.removeMessages(ACTION_PLAY_SOUND)
                        return
                    }

                    logDebug("SoundPoolHandlerThread: Playing sound!")
                    logDebug("SoundPoolHandlerThread: ${soundPoolSoundsQueue.size} sounds left for playing.")

                    val soundPoolSound = soundPoolSoundsQueue.pop()
                    soundPool.play(soundPoolSound.soundPoolSoundId,
                            soundPoolSound.leftVolume,
                            soundPoolSound.rightVolume,
                            soundPoolSound.priority,
                            if(soundPoolSound.loop) { 1 } else { 0 },
                            soundPoolSound.rate)

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(soundPoolSound.duration)
                    }
                    catch (ex: InterruptedException) { }

                    //soundPoolQueueListener?.onSoundPlaybackCompleted(soundPoolSound.soundResId)
                    sendEmptyMessage(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface SoundPoolQueueListener {
        fun onSoundPlaybackCompleted(soundResId: Int)
    }
}
```

The accompanying data class

```
data class SoundPoolSound(val duration: Long,
                      val soundResId: Int,
                      val soundPoolSoundId: Int,
                      val leftVolume: Float,
                      val rightVolume: Float,
                      val priority: Int,
                      val loop: Boolean,
                      val rate: Float)
```

You will get notified when sound has completed playing in the

```
onSoundPlaybackCompleted(soundResId: Int)
```

with the resouce id of the completed playback sound.

Usage example:

```
 private class SoundPoolRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            LogUtils.debug(SerializableNames.LOG_TAG, "SoundPoolRunnable:run(): Initializing sounds!");

            m_soundPoolPlayer = new SoundPoolQueue(GSMSignalMonitorApp.this, 1);
            m_soundPoolPlayer.setSoundPoolQueueListener(new SoundPoolQueue.SoundPoolQueueListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSoundPlaybackCompleted(int soundResId)
                {
                    LogUtils.debug(SerializableNames.LOG_TAG, "onSoundPlaybackCompleted() " + soundResId);
                }
            });

            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_lost, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);
            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_restored, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);
            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_low, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);

            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_lost_ru, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);
            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_restored_ru, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);
            m_soundPoolPlayer.addSound(R.raw.gsm_signal_low_ru, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1, false, 1.0f);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps :)