# Android: How to know that playback of the SoundPool has ended?

Tags: android, soundpool

Maybe anybody faced with this issue.
I use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) for playing sounds in my app.
After playing the sound I need to do further action. But how can I determine that the sound has stoped?
All the sounds in the app have a different length, so I can not count the time. I need a different approach.
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436055/android-soundpool-get-notified-when-end-of-played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

soundpool's purpose is to load and play simple small sounds without the need to monitor them.

what you probably need is MediaPlayer and setOnCompletionListener() :

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)