# (Android) How to tell if a sound is playing in soundpool

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

Is there a way I can tell if a certain sound is playing in SoundPool???
I.E.

```
    if(MySound./*Command Goes Here*/()==true{
//Do stuff
        }
```

I would appreciate if you could point me in the right direction or give me the code. I am not able to find any thing that does this on the docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SoundPool: get notified when end of played](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436055/android-soundpool-get-notified-when-end-of-played)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using `SoundPool`.

See [Android SoundPool: get notified when end of played](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436055/android-soundpool-get-notified-when-end-of-played) for two other ideas:

- Use `MediaPlayer`, which provides an `OnCompletionListener`, instead of `SoundPool`
- Use `MediaPlayer` in conjunction with `SoundPool`. Load the sound in a `MediaPlayer` beforehand to get the duration and keep track of whether the sound is done playing based its duration when played with `SoundPool`.

Comment: `MediaPLayer` also has methods for `isPlaying()`, `getCurrentPosition()`, `getTrackInfo()` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I will do what @Squonk and load in MediaPlayer and get the length there. Thanks for your answer.